# nsdate group according to week/ year

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am generating a graph based on date. User will select start date and end date.

For eg if start date is 3/10/13 and end date is 15/10/13. I want to group the dates by week.

So the grouping should be like 3/10/2013 - 5/10/13 , 6/10/13 - 12/10/13 , 13/10/13 - 15/10/13.

Using **nsdatecomponents** I can find the difference between 2 dates.

```
    NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract  = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:stDate  toDate:endDate options:0];
```

But how to group them by week??

Comment: Grouping by week like what ? I mean what will be the condition for week and months ? How can only week distinguish all dates ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you choose a starting date then just add exactly 7 days to that and grab everything between those for the first week, add  days to the date, and grab everything between those dates for the 2nd week and so on.

If you always want to start with a Sunday (or could be monday) use date components to pick a date that is a Sunday:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:yourApproximateStartingDate];

[components setWeekday:1]; // 1 == Sunday
yourStartingDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSTimeInterval sevenDays = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;
NSDate *secondDate = [yourStartingDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:sevenDays];
```

Then you can use a comparator to see which dates are in that range.